# What is the simplest way to convert str (eg: 28/01/2023 13:17:58) to datetime(2023/01/28 13:17:58) format in python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have tried multiple ways like splitting each value and the rearranging. and the code seems too lengthy can someone help me to write it in a shorter way.

> time = "28/01/2023 13:17:58"
> I split it to

```
lis = [28,01,2023]
lis2 = [13,17,58]
```

then rearranged it to

```
t = 28/01/2023 13:17:58
```

can someone tell me how I can use datetime to simplify this?

Comment: Did you look at [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)?

Comment: @Delgan tried that but it was throwing error while trying to convert directly from string to datetime

Comment: Parsing directive `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"` ?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string "Jun 1 2005 1:33PM" into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/convert-string-jun-1-2005-133pm-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date =  "28/01/2023 13:17:58"

`datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Output = `datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 28, 13, 17, 58)`

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

time = "28/01/2023 13:17:58"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(time, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(datetime_obj) # 2023-01-28 13:17:58
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: @FObersteiner, Abhishek, I believe at first I didn't understood the question. have updated.